# wp_link_pages return value even when is condition inside if statement

Tags: php, paginate-links

I am trying to check if wp_link_pages is true in this way:

```
                        <?php 
                            the_content(); 
                            if( wp_link_pages() ):
                        ?>

                        <ul class="post-paginate">
                            <li class="inline-block">
                                <?php if( !isset( $_GET['view'] ) && $_GET['view'] != 'all' ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?view=all" class="dharmagothicc-regular gold">SINGLE PAGE - </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>                                     
                            </li>
                            <li class="inline-block numbers dharmagothicc-regular">
                                <?php wp_link_pages(array('next_or_number'=>'number', 'before'=>'')); ?>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that `wp_link_pages()` return the value two times - even when is the condition in the `if()` statement.

Is there a way to escape this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if( wp_link_pages() )` does not make sense because the function is meant to produce result rather than check for condition and defaults to echoing said result.

Applicability of using it like this aside, `if( wp_link_pages('echo=0') )`, or something along, that should silence that copy of output.